# Why doesn't this date filter work for Google custom search engine?

Tags: google-custom-search

I have the following URL for Google Custom Search:
https://cse.google.com/cse/publicurl?cx=009109446831433497335:uygplyffubi&q=valuation&sort=date:r::20151231

However, the date is clearly not filtering if you look at the results. Can somebody please advise? I haven't found any good answers.

Answer (score 0):

In setup, go to search features, results sorting, and check soft by date.

Comment: Should it be "sort by date"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't want to just "sort by date", is it possible to "filter" by date?